# In angular2 & nativescript the *ngFor display array's elements on top of each other

Tags: css, arrays, angular, nativescript, ngfor

I am populating an array with user's input and would like to render on the same page, the data from that array. I m using *ngFor to do that  but it displays the elements on top of each other. 
**The html is:**

```
<Gridlayout class="main-container" columns="auto" rows="auto,auto,auto">
    <StackLayout  exampleTitle toggleNavButton row="0" class="set-hour">
        <!-- >> creating-timepicker-html -->
            <timePicker class="example-container" #timePicker (loaded)="configure(timePicker)" verticalAlignment="center"></timePicker>
            <Button text="Add hour" (tap)="onTap()"></Button>

        <!-- << creating-timepicker-html -->
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout row="1" class="hour" *ngFor="let hour of hours">
        <Label [text]='hour.hour'></Label>
        <Label [text]='hour.minute'></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</Gridlayout>
```

**the ts is:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef} from "@angular/core";
import { UserService} from "../../../services/user.service";
import { TimePicker } from "ui/time-picker";
import { HoursModel } from "../../../models/hours.model";

@Component({
  selector: "hours",
  templateUrl:"components/profile/hours/hours.component.html",
  styleUrls:["components/profile/hours/hours.component.css"]
})

export class HoursComponent implements OnInit{

    @ViewChild("timePicker") tp: ElementRef;

    public hours:Array<HoursModel>=[];
    public index:number=0;

    constructor(){}

    ngOnInit(){}

    configure(timePicker: TimePicker) {
        timePicker.hour = 21;
        timePicker.minute = 0;  
    }

    onTap() {
        let time =this.tp.nativeElement;
        this.hours.push(<HoursModel>{id:this.index,hour:time.hour,minute:time.minute});
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.hours));
        this.index++;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try using an ObservableArray ? https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/data/observable-array

also you could try the ChangeDetectorRef detectCahnges() method

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you would like to display data within a list. 
Try to use this code:

```
<ListView [items]="hours | async" >
<ng-template let-item="hour" >
<StackLayout>
<Label [text]='hour.hour'></Label>
<Label [text]='hour.minute'></Label>
</StackLayout>
</ng-template> 
</ListView>
```

With your current code you continuously add the data on top of each other, because the parent component is the page itself. 
List view is the UI elements that you search.

Comment: thanks for the info. so i have replaced the code and it still doesn t work. even more when i click done it adds the element to the array, it doesn't display the value and  the time picker and click events don t work.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. Just update the code, more info on https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/list-view.html

Comment: should I edit the .ts file? becouse it still doesn t work

Comment: Using observables you must use the async pipe: [items]="hours | async", because the code must be updated every time there is a change.